# How to categorize rows in the free grid jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqpivot

Hi i have the following table to generate a json dataset

[image: DB table design]

it has the following data i have script teh table

```sql
USE [GridSamples]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SalesStats]    Script Date: 12/13/2016 07:34:51 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesStats](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [makes] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [models] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [fuelusagecity] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [fuelusagehwy] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [salesaboveavg] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [totalnumofsales] [money] NOT NULL,
    [highsalestext] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [saledate] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SalesStats] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SalesStats] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[SalesStats] ([id], [makes], [models], [fuelusagecity], [fuelusagehwy], [salesaboveavg], [totalnumofsales], [highsalestext], [saledate]) VALUES (1, N'toyota    ', N'corolla   ', N'17        ', N'12        ', 0, 120000.0000, NULL, CAST(0x9A330B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SalesStats] ([id], [makes], [models], [fuelusagecity], [fuelusagehwy], [salesaboveavg], [totalnumofsales], [highsalestext], [saledate]) VALUES (2, N'toyota    ', N'corolla   ', N'10        ', N'14        ', 0, 100000.0000, N'HIGH', CAST(0xA8330B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SalesStats] ([id], [makes], [models], [fuelusagecity], [fuelusagehwy], [salesaboveavg], [totalnumofsales], [highsalestext], [saledate]) VALUES (3, N'toyota    ', N'belta     ', N'15        ', N'10        ', 1, 200000.0000, NULL, CAST(0xC2330B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SalesStats] ([id], [makes], [models], [fuelusagecity], [fuelusagehwy], [salesaboveavg], [totalnumofsales], [highsalestext], [saledate]) VALUES (4, N'toyota    ', N'camry     ', N'13        ', N'10        ', 0, 300000.0000, N'HIGH', CAST(0x29340B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SalesStats] ([id], [makes], [models], [fuelusagecity], [fuelusagehwy], [salesaboveavg], [totalnumofsales], [highsalestext], [saledate]) VALUES (5, N'nissan    ', N'skyline   ', N'14        ', N'9         ', 1, 500000.0000, N'HIGH', CAST(0x48330B00 AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SalesStats] ([id], [makes], [models], [fuelusagecity], [fuelusagehwy], [salesaboveavg], [totalnumofsales], [highsalestext], [saledate]) VALUES (6, N'nissan    ', N'zx300     ', N'10        ', N'8         ', 0, 400000.0000, NULL, CAST(0x2B350B00 AS Date))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SalesStats] OFF
GO
```

In my middle tier ASP MVC the controller converts this to the the following json **(UPADATED TO HAVE A STRING SalesDate)**

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"make":"toyota","model":"corolla","fuelusagecity":"17","fuelusagehwy":"12","salesaboveavg":false,"totalnumberofsales":120000.0000,"highsalestext":null,"salesdate":"2010-12-01"},{"id":2,"make":"toyota","model":"corolla","fuelusagecity":"10","fuelusagehwy":"14","salesaboveavg":false,"totalnumberofsales":100000.0000,"highsalestext":"HIGH","salesdate":"2010-12-15"},{"id":3,"make":"toyota","model":"belta","fuelusagecity":"15","fuelusagehwy":"10","salesaboveavg":true,"totalnumberofsales":200000.0000,"highsalestext":null,"salesdate":"2011-01-10"},{"id":4,"make":"toyota","model":"camry","fuelusagecity":"13","fuelusagehwy":"10","salesaboveavg":false,"totalnumberofsales":300000.0000,"highsalestext":"HIGH","salesdate":"2011-04-23"},{"id":5,"make":"nissan","model":"skyline","fuelusagecity":"14","fuelusagehwy":"9","salesaboveavg":true,"totalnumberofsales":500000.0000,"highsalestext":"HIGH","salesdate":"2010-09-10"},{"id":6,"make":"nissan","model":"zx300","fuelusagecity":"10","fuelusagehwy":"8","salesaboveavg":false,"totalnumberofsales":400000.0000,"highsalestext":null,"salesdate":"2012-01-06"}];
```

i have used the following code to generate the grid using JqGrid free-grid. for easiness i have added the above `json` array to the `data` array

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<table id="list483"></table>
<div id=""></div>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.5/js/i18n/grid.locale-de.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.5/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [{"id":1,"make":"toyota","model":"corolla","fuelusagecity":"17","fuelusagehwy":"12","salesaboveavg":false,"totalnumberofsales":120000.0000,"highsalestext":null,"salesdate":"2010-12-01"},{"id":2,"make":"toyota","model":"corolla","fuelusagecity":"10","fuelusagehwy":"14","salesaboveavg":false,"totalnumberofsales":100000.0000,"highsalestext":"HIGH","salesdate":"2010-12-15"},{"id":3,"make":"toyota","model":"belta","fuelusagecity":"15","fuelusagehwy":"10","salesaboveavg":true,"totalnumberofsales":200000.0000,"highsalestext":null,"salesdate":"2011-01-10"},{"id":4,"make":"toyota","model":"camry","fuelusagecity":"13","fuelusagehwy":"10","salesaboveavg":false,"totalnumberofsales":300000.0000,"highsalestext":"HIGH","salesdate":"2011-04-23"},{"id":5,"make":"nissan","model":"skyline","fuelusagecity":"14","fuelusagehwy":"9","salesaboveavg":true,"totalnumberofsales":500000.0000,"highsalestext":"HIGH","salesdate":"2010-09-10"},{"id":6,"make":"nissan","model":"zx300","fuelusagecity":"10","fuelusagehwy":"8","salesaboveavg":false,"totalnumberofsales":400000.0000,"highsalestext":null,"salesdate":"2012-01-06"}];


    $("#list483").jqGrid("jqPivot",
            data,
            {
                frozenStaticCols: true,
                xDimension: [
                    {/*x0*/ dataName: "make", width: 200, label: "Make" },
                    {/*x1*/ dataName: "model", skipGrouping: true },
                    {/*x2*/ dataName: "fuelusagecity", hidden: true, skipGrouping: true },
                    {/*x3*/ dataName: "fuelusagehwy", width: 80, align: "center",
                        label: "fuel consumption", skipGrouping: true,
                        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                            return rowObject.x2 === null || rowObject.x3 === null ?
                                    "-" :
                            String(rowObject.x2) + "-" + String(cellvalue);
                        }
                    },
                    {/*x4*/ dataName: "salesaboveavg", hidden: true, width: 50, align: "center", skipGrouping: true },
                    {/*x5*/ dataName: "highsalestext", hidden: true, skipGrouping: true }
                ],
                yDimension: [
                    {/*y0*/    dataName: "salesdate",
                    sorttype: "date",
                        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        //var x = rawObject.y0;
                        console.log(rowObject);
//                            return rowObject;
                    }
                }],
                aggregates: [{
                    member: "totalnumberofsales",
                    aggregator: "max"
                }]
            },
// grid options
            {
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, width: 90 },
                shrinkToFit: false,
                useUnformattedDataForCellAttr: false,
                autoResizing: { compact: true },
                groupingView: {
                    groupField: ["x0"],
                    groupColumnShow: [false],
                    groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>']
                },
                width: 450,
                pager: true,
                rowNum: 20,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100, "10000:All"],
                caption: "<b>Car sales statistics</b>"
            }
    );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the generated grid is shown below image link

[image]

i have so many questions relating to this grid. but i will post them one by one as answers progresses. But for now the following questions to start off with:

> 1. when i turned on teh grouping what happened to teh collapse icon image that should appear behind the group name? **SOLVED: i have found the answer to this question, the missing font-awesome library caused the issue**
> 2. How do i convert the json dates in teh dates columns and display them in actual dates?**SOLVED:This issue was solved once i made the conversion in the middle tier to return saledate a string value**

3. The Grid has two entries on the Toyota Corolla but this should be one entry and in that entry, `totalnumofsales` values should be placed on the two matching dates. AKA in a single row entry to toyota corolla `120000` in `2010-12-01` cell and `100000` in `2010-12-15` 
   also teh fuel consuption value must be the first row value i.e. 10-14
4. for the cell that don't have values shows 0.00 instead of showing 0.00 i need them to display an empty cell
5. How do i turn off the automatic sorting of the grid becuase when grid is generated the groups names are sorted in the alphabetical order but i dont wont grid to sort them, instead keep their original order that comes from the backend

how do i acheive the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think origin of your question are some common misunderstanding what is pivot table and how one can use it. I try to explain all below in details on an example of your input data.

You use the following input data:

```json
[{
    "id": 1,
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "corolla",
    "fuelusagecity": "17",
    "fuelusagehwy": "12",
    "salesaboveavg": false,
    "totalnumberofsales": 120000.0000,
    "highsalestext": null,
    "salesdate": "2010-12-01"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "corolla",
    "fuelusagecity": "10",
    "fuelusagehwy": "14",
    "salesaboveavg": false,
    "totalnumberofsales": 100000.0000,
    "highsalestext": "HIGH",
    "salesdate": "2010-12-15"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "belta",
    "fuelusagecity": "15",
    "fuelusagehwy": "10",
    "salesaboveavg": true,
    "totalnumberofsales": 200000.0000,
    "highsalestext": null,
    "salesdate": "2011-01-10"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "camry",
    "fuelusagecity": "13",
    "fuelusagehwy": "10",
    "salesaboveavg": false,
    "totalnumberofsales": 300000.0000,
    "highsalestext": "HIGH",
    "salesdate": "2011-04-23"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "make": "nissan",
    "model": "skyline",
    "fuelusagecity": "14",
    "fuelusagehwy": "9",
    "salesaboveavg": true,
    "totalnumberofsales": 500000.0000,
    "highsalestext": "HIGH",
    "salesdate": "2010-09-10"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "make": "nissan",
    "model": "zx300",
    "fuelusagecity": "10",
    "fuelusagehwy": "8",
    "salesaboveavg": false,
    "totalnumberofsales": 400000.0000,
    "highsalestext": null,
    "salesdate": "2012-01-06"
}]
```

Every item of data have many properties. Some properties contains different (or even unique) values (like `id`). Other properties should be grouped together and calculate some **aggregation** function on another properties on every item **inside of the group**. I explain the above statement on an example.

The input data contains sale information of some car models. It could be interesting, for example, to display the number of sales of every car model by date or by year etc.

Pivot tables contains three main parameters `xDimension`, `yDimension` and `aggregates`. For example, look at the following picture below
[image]
The left part (markt in orange) represents `xDimension` (`make` and `model`). It build mostly *the rows* of the grid. The right part (marked in blue) represents `yDimension` (`year` and `month` of the input items). The lowest level of the information on the right size contains the result of calculation of aggregate functions (`max` and `count`) on some input property (it was `totalnumberofsales` in the example).

If one defined only one aggregate function inside of `aggregates` parameter, then the name of aggregate function will be not displayed:
[image]

Now I have to display what jqPivot do to create jqGrid. First of all it scan all input data by all X and by Y parameters. If you define for example the following pivot model

```js
xDimension: [
    { dataName: "make", width: 100, label: "Make" },
    { dataName: "model", width: 100, label: "Model", align: "center" }
],
yDimension: [
    { dataName: "salesdate", sortorder: "desc" }
],
aggregates: [
    { member: "totalnumberofsales", aggregator: "max" }
]
```

then all data will be first scanned for the items having the same `["make", "model"]` values in `xDimension` and by `["salesdate"]` in `yDimension`. The input data has 6 elements with the indexes from 0 till 5. The resulting xIndexes and yIndexes contains unique values by x and y and the indexes of source data (from 0 till 5) to the items, which has the data. One can add the following lines after jqPivot call to see the indexes:

```js
var p = $("#list483").jqGrid("getGridParam");
console.log(JSON.stringify(p.pivotOptions.xIndex));
console.log(JSON.stringify(p.pivotOptions.yIndex));
```

As the result one will see the demo https://jsfiddle.net/oadzsnov/. I include the resulting xIndex and yIndex below. xIndex is

```json
{
    "items": [
        ["toyota", "corolla"],
        ["toyota", "belta"],
        ["toyota", "camry"],
        ["nissan", "skyline"],
        ["nissan", "zx300"]
    ],
    "indexesOfSourceData": [
        [0, 1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5]
    ],
    "trimByCollect": true,
    "caseSensitive": false,
    "skipSort": true,
    "fieldLength": 2,
    "fieldNames": ["make", "model"],
    "fieldSortDirection": [1, 1],
    "fieldCompare": [null, null]
}
```

yIndex is

```json
{
    "items": [
        ["2012-01-06"],
        ["2011-04-23"],
        ["2011-01-10"],
        ["2010-12-15"],
        ["2010-12-01"],
        ["2010-09-10"]
    ],
    "indexesOfSourceData": [
        [5],
        [3],
        [2],
        [1],
        [0],
        [4]
    ],
    "trimByCollect": true,
    "caseSensitive": false,
    "skipSort": false,
    "fieldLength": 1,
    "fieldNames": ["salesdate"],
    "fieldSortDirection": [-1],
    "fieldCompare": [null]
}
```

The `xIndex.items` build the rows of the resulting pivot table and `yIndex` build the columns. You can see that the rows will be

```json
["toyota", "corolla"],
["toyota", "belta"],
["toyota", "camry"],
["nissan", "skyline"],
["nissan", "zx300"]
```

and the columns:

```json
["2012-01-06"],
["2011-04-23"],
["2011-01-10"],
["2010-12-15"],
["2010-12-01"],
["2010-09-10"]
```

One can see additionally that 2 elements of source data (see `xIndex.indexesOfSourceData`, which is `[0, 1]`) `xIndex.items` corresponds the same x-vector `["toyota", "corolla"]`. The content of the pivot table (see yellow marked data on the first picture) will be the result of executing the specified aggregate function. We used

```js
aggregates: [
    { member: "totalnumberofsales", aggregator: "max" }
]
```

and the source elements with the index 0 and 1 are

```json
[{
    ...
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "corolla",
    ...
    "totalnumberofsales": 120000.0000,
    ...
    "salesdate": "2010-12-01"
}, {
    ...
    "make": "toyota",
    "model": "corolla",
    ...
    "totalnumberofsales": 100000.0000,
    ...
    "salesdate": "2010-12-15"
}
```

The items have *different y-vectors* (`"salesdate": "2010-12-01"` for the first item and `"salesdate": "2010-12-15"` for the second one). Thus the calculation of aggregates will be very simple: `120000` in the column `"2010-12-01"`, `100000` in the column `"2010-12-15"` and `0` for all other dates, because there are no `["toyota", "corolla"]` sales at the day:

[image]

If you would assign *separate* `salesYear` and `salesMonth` properties based on the `salesdate`, then you can use

```js
xDimension: [
    { dataName: "make", width: 100, label: "Make" },
    { dataName: "model", width: 100, label: "Model", align: "center" }
],
yDimension: [
    { dataName: "salesYear", sorttype: "integer" },
    { dataName: "salesMonth", sorttype: "integer" }
],
aggregates: [{
    member: "totalnumberofsales",
    aggregator: "max"
}]
```

to create the pivot table. Both first source items has the same `salesdate` (`"2010-12-15"` and `"2010-12-15"`). The calculation of `max` aggregater over the both items get `120000`, which one will see in the resulting grid

[image]

see https://jsfiddle.net/fa40onkz/

If you could follow me till the place, then you could understand any from effect, which you could see in the resulting pivot table.

For example, it's wrong to use

```js
{/*x2*/ dataName: "fuelusagecity", hidden: true, skipGrouping: true },
{/*x3*/ dataName: "fuelusagehwy", width: 80, align: "center",
    label: "fuel consumption", skipGrouping: true,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return rowObject.x2 === null || rowObject.x3 === null ?
                "-" :
        String(rowObject.x2) + "-" + String(cellvalue);
    }
},
{/*x4*/ dataName: "salesaboveavg", hidden: true, width: 50, align: "center", skipGrouping: true },
{/*x5*/ dataName: "highsalestext", hidden: true, skipGrouping: true }
```

in option of jqPivot, because two `["toyota", "corolla"]` source items have **different** `fuelusagecity`, `fuelusagehwy` and `highsalestext` values. The `salesaboveavg` value is the same, but I suppose the usage of `salesaboveavg` is the same error. **You should remove the items from `xDimension`.**

To display empty cell in the cells with `0` value you can define column template

```js
var myIntTemplate = {
    formatter: "currency",
    align: "right", sorttype: "number",
    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"] },
    formatoptions: { defaultValue: ""}};
```

and to use it in `aggregates`:

```js
aggregates: [{
    member: "cellvalue",
    template: myIntTemplate,
    aggregator: "max"
}]
```

You will get the results like
[image]

like on the demo https://jsfiddle.net/tnr2dgkv/

Your last question was about sorting. Sorting of source items is extremely important to create correct pivot table. You can use `skipSortByX: true` or/and `skipSortByY: true` options of jqPivot to suppress sorting of initial data, but the resulting data will be sorted once more if you use grouping (`groupField: ["x0"]`). I think that the simplest way (but it's still not so simple in the implementation) to hold the order of resulting items would be by defining custom sorting functions for `xDimension` items. I recommend you to read [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive explanation of the pivot. : )  So it states that in the pivots i cannot place string text they must be numbers. this is becuase the aggregate wont let me insert numbers. So in order to have those string text placed on pivot like cells i cannot choose the pivot grid instead i have to opt for a grouped column grid with dynamic column set for salesdates, am i correct?

Comment: @Dore.Ad: You are welcome! I can't answer about your question about strings because I don't have any realistic example. The value in the cells could be a text in general, but it should be **generated** from set of items. For example, you can place the name of month ("Jan", "Feb", ..) in which one had the largest amount of sales, but you have to define an aggregation function (`aggregator` callback in `aggregates`: see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.6/js/grid.pivot.js#L73-L80)) which makes the corresponding calculation and returns the string.

Comment: i will accept this as an explanatory reply stating pivot cells must be numbers since they use aggregate options

Comment: @Dore.Ad: Please don't post any "commutative questions" in the future (with separate sub-questions), because it's prohibited by the policy of stackowerflow (read FAQ). The reason of the restriction is very easy to understand. Stackoverflow is *not a forum*, where somebody could help you to solve *your specific problems*. Stackoverflow shares *common* questions with answers, which could help *many* people. Thus one have to formulate questions so, that there could be better indexed by searching engine (like Google) and be found by other people. Thus one should post separate questions with tags.